# how to open a RCP Application based on GMF Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, rcp

i really need some help for open a Rcp application based on GMF Framework
Now i design a editor with GMF and run as "Eclipse Application".
i want to run this application with code
i can overirde this method to run the application

```
@Override
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    try {
        int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display,
                new CefSrcRouteFlow.diagram.application.DiagramEditorWorkbenchAdvisor());
        if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
            return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
        }
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    } finally {
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

but for this IApplicationContext as argument,
how can i get a instance for this?

Answer (score 0):

To run an Eclipse RCP `start` class you must define the application using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point and specify the name of your `IApplication` class in the `run` element:

```xml
<extension
     id="application"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
  <application>
     <run
           class="testrcp.Application">
     </run>
  </application>
</extension>
```

You can then test this using 'Run > Eclipse Application'.

Eclipe will call the `start` method providing the `IApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

thank you  for your reply. its possible to run it with code, not with "Run AS->Eclipse Application". now i have a GUI Interface with JAVA FX. This Gui has a Button, Wenn the user click the Button, the Rcp Editor should be started?